# PHP, CodeIgniter, Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have this website wherein I need to debug, but I can't seem to get the data from this checkbox ..

```
     <?php
                    foreach ($callers as $block)
                    {
                        if($block->block_status==1)
                        {?>
                                        <div class="col-md-1">
                                             <input type="checkbox" name="block_cb[]">
                                        </div>
                                            <input class="block_id" name="block_id[]" type="hidden" 
                                            value="<?php echo $block->id;?>"> 

                                            <div class="col-md-6"> <?php echo $block->block_number;?></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-5"><?php echo $block->block_date;?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

And I have this button ..

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/block/update/<?php echo $block->id;?> "id="unblock">Unblock</button>
```

This goes to the function updateblock()

Eventually discovered this Javascript, but don't know how to apply this script to the code above.

```
function unBlock(){
var id = [];
var status = [];
var curpage = $('#curpage').val();
hidden = []; 
$('input[name="block_id[]"]').each(function(){
    id.push($(this).val());
});
$('input[name="block_cb[]"]').each(function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
         toastr.success('Number Unblocked'); 
         status.push(0);
         var hiddenpush =  $(this).parents('#idfind').find('.block_id').val();
         hidden.push(hiddenpush);
         $(this).parents('.gbItem').addClass('hidden');
     }    
     else{
         status.push(1);
     }

for(var a = 0; a < id.length ; a++){
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+curpage+"/dashboard/updateblock",
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            'user_id' : id[a],
            'block_status': status[a],
        },
    }); 
 }
```

This is where the link goes.

```
  function updateblock(){

     //This is the original code. 
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $data['block_status'] = $_POST['block_status'];
        $this->block_model->update_blocked_number($id,$data);


    /*
    $id = $id;
    //$data['block_status'] = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $data['block_status'] = 111;        
    $this->block_model->update_blocked_number($id,$data);
    */

}
```

How can I get the data from the checkboxes (which is an array) to the button. I'll be passing the ID from the URL. Thank you.

E.g link/here/6 where 6 should be the ID I should get from the checkboxes.

Comment: Close your php tag near if($block->block_status==1)
                        {

Comment: Sorry I accidentally deleted that one. But still won't work. How can I get the data from the foreach to the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php echo anchor(BASE_URL.'link/here','Unblock',
 array('class'=>"btn btn-danger",'onClick'=>'unBlock()')); ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php echo anchor(BASE_URL.'link/here','Unblock', 'class="btn btn-danger new-action"'); ?>

$('.new-action').click(function(e){
    e.preventdefault();
    var id = [];
    var status = [];
    var curpage = $('#curpage').val();
    hidden = []; 
    $('input[name="block_id[]"]').each(function(){
           id.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('input[name="block_cb[]"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
         toastr.success('Number Unblocked'); 
         status.push(0);
         var hiddenpush =  $(this).parents('#idfind').find('.block_id').val();
         hidden.push(hiddenpush);
         $(this).parents('.gbItem').addClass('hidden');
    }    
    else{
         status.push(1);
     }

});
```

Comment: it wont put parameters in your link. It will bind click event on anchor

Comment: what issue you are facing after using this?

Comment: Is there anything I need to put in the controller? I have posted the controller->function in the post.

Comment: where are you adding anchor tag. You have to change as 1st option in my answer. But as you are adding link also in anchor tag so before run javascript code your page will be redirected. So it wont work

Comment: you changed `anchor` to `button`. button has no any attribute `herf` so it also wont work and to get value from checkbox give value to it

Comment: Yes. That's why I need to get the data from the checkbox to the link in the button.

Comment: You are confusing me. What is your exact problem?

Comment: You see the checkboxes code, right? I need to get the ID from those checkboxes so that I can pass it through the URL. Unfortunately, the information is in a foreach{}, thus, not allowing me to access the said data.

Comment: where you want to add this url? you need to use foreach to get these data

Comment: <button class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/block/update/<?php echo $block->id;?>.. Here. I need to substitute "$block->id" to all the selected data.